# How can I get C++ string functions to behave like Java and C# string methods?

Tags: c++, string

I am starting to learn some C++ coming from a general programming background with knowledge of Java and C#. I am working with some strings, and I am frustrated with some of the string functions. I am used to string functions returning a new string leaving the old one intact. I understand that this is done in C# and Java because the strings are immutable, but I really wish the string methods in C++ worked this way as well. Is there anything I'm missing? right now I am doing something like this:

```
std::string temp = word;
Func(temp.erase(i , 1));
```

Edit: This is kind of what I was thinking:

```
Func(word.substr().erase(i , 1);
```

Which of these do you all think is best? Its a minor thing I suppose, just wondering.

Comment: Doesn't that erase nothing?

Comment: Yeah... what exactly are you trying to do with the string?

Comment: I'm not sure you're missing anything.  C++ strings are really just containers, so they're semantically quite similar to e.g. vectors.  If you want a copy of the entire thing, then all you need to do is create one.

Comment: Wish as you might, C++ is not C# and never will be.  Instead of trying to turn it into another language, embrace the language that is (with its warts) and consider it a completely separate entity (because it is)

Comment: If you want to write C# or Java, write C# or Java. Don't try to make one language into another.

Comment: Yes, I had a typo in the call to erase. I do not wish to change c++, just wondering what the best way to work with some of the warts is :)

Comment: @Ben313: Ok, but realize that your latest statements contradict the title and almost every sentence in your question.

Comment: @Ben313 write your own immutable string class, just wrap std::string, shouldn't be that much work.

Comment: `Func(std::string(word).erase(i, 1));`

Answer (score 1):

In C++ you have both posibilities: "in place" editing , or to return a new string you can use [substr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) for example.

OK, I see. A variant of that:

```
Func( string(word).erase(i,1) );
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Not sure if I should be using it or not though.

Comment: It's acceptable to use when you actually need a copy (even a temporary copy that you pass in to functions), but by default, you should modify the original, especially if you are using the same member-function (like **erase**) multiple times with the same arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you want a copy, explicitely declare it:

```
std::string copy = original;
copy.erase(startPos, size);
```

Constantly copying strings when you don't actually need copies is a waste of performance, and C++ is designed to be extremely high performing so large programs (like games, or office suites, or web browsers) can run smoothly even on old hardware.

C++'s motto, to meet this very important need, is "*Don't pay for what you don't need*", and the entire language is designed around that.

This doesn't mean other languages, like Java, are worse or better, just that they serve a different purpose and different needs, and so function differently. Java's primary purpose is "*Run the same executable anywhere and everywhere*" (literally: "*[write once, run everywhere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_once,_run_anywhere)*"), which is why it exists on a virtual machine, and why Java code works on $10 cellphones, $1000 smart phones, TVs, computers, web browsers, and your microwave.